# What kind of foot pump would I need to build a DIY camping sink?

Tags: camping, diy

I want to build a simple DIY foot pump based camping sink. I can't seem to understand what kind of foot pump should I be buying. I don't know what is the exact term for this kind of foot pump:

[image: An image seen on Instructables article]
http://www.instructables.com/id/Field-Sink/step2/Materials/

What is the term for this kind of foot pump? I reside in Bangalore, India and have access to local hardware stores close by.

I also found this product online: 
[image: Foot pump product on Amazon.in]

http://www.amazon.in/Intex-Bellows-Foot-Pump-Hi/dp/B00YH5VL2A?ie=UTF8&keywords=foot%20pump&qid=1475573380.

Will this be able to hook up with my DIY camping sink? I selected this particular one as it's easily returnable should things not work out. I have a budget constraint as well. I have never done any kind of plumbing but I am fairly resourceful.

Comment: I think that pump will be too lightweight to deal with water, this one looks more likely https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Siphon-Liquid-Transfer-Squeeze/dp/B00AXNX6M8

Comment: What is the pumps job in this?

Comment: @ChrisJ I can't from US Amazon but thanks for the link.

Comment: @sindhus - try this https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=siphon+pump&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Asiphon+pump you're looking for pumps that move water as opposed to air, air pumps won't work nearly as well

Comment: @ChrisJ thank you sooo much!! that's exactly what I wanted. Siphon pump was the term I was grokking around for.

Comment: @sindhus glad to help, I'm not an expert so might be some one better informed

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh because then you would need a valve to turn the water on and off, a foot pump is going to give you much better options to limit water wastage.

Answer (score 6):

I've used the "primer bulb pump with check valve" before and it worked great. It's made for boat outboard motors. It comes in a few hose sizes. Do you have a marina or boat supply store near by? If not check on Amazon.

primer bulb pump with check valve ($5 - $20 USD):
[image]

Like this:
[image]